# How do you differentiate private member variable in objective-c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, private, member

for private methods,

I could use

```
@interface MyClass(PrivateMethods)
- (void) _foo;
@end
```

How do you declare a private member variable in objective c?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocDefiningClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH12-TPXREF127

```
@interface MyClass : Superclass {

@private
    NSString * privateString;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare it as follows..

```
@private //variable;
```

Check this question out.
[Question- private-instance-variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262463/how-to-make-a-real-private-instance-variable)