# Define instance Variables without property

Tags: objective-c, properties

I know that it is possible in Objective C to define an instance variable without a property when I use curly braces in the top of the interface or the implementation. But what is the advantage when I do that?

Comment: Don't look for advantages. It's archaism of objective-c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your question should be comparing to property what is the advantage of defining instance variables.

Most property is backed by a instance variables. By default, a readwrite property will be backed by an instance variable, which will be synthesized automatically by the compiler. (A readonly property won't synthesize an instance variable, it only synthesizes a getter method which a readwrite property synthesize an instance variable and a getter and a setter method)

So property provides methods that synthesized by compiler to access the instance variable. I can't say which one has any advantages, just use the one which is proper to your case.

You may need to learn more about property. [Properties Encapsulate an Object’s Values](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html)

Answer (score 0):

The most advantage is this variables actually can be private/protected/public members according to the keyword (@private/@protected/@public) you set.

Take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262463/how-to-make-a-real-private-instance-variable)